# Не работает AJAX на странице Django

Tags: django, ajax

У меня fullstack проект на Django, я реализовал корзину через сессии. Теперь нужно сделать добавление в корзину без перезагрузки страницы. Однако, у меня это не работает. Выводит тупо json. Полагаю, что проблема во views.py и AJAX. Так как ранее не использовал эту технологию, то буду благодарен любой инфе. Не могу понять как связать views с AJAX?

views.py:

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=1)
    cart.add(product=product)
    response = {'success': True, 'message': 'Товар успешно добавлен в корзину.'}
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

html:

```
<form action="{% url 'add_cart' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="submit" value="Добавить в корзину" class="itm-btn">
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addToCartForm, #removeFromCartForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
          
        var form = $(this);
          
        $.ajax({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
            // Должно выполняться это
            alert('666')
            } else {
            alert('Произошла ошибка: ' + response.message);
            }
             },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  alert('Произошла ошибка при обработке запроса.');
                }
              });
              return false;
            });
          });
```

Comment: Что насчёт наличия или отсутствия ошибок в браузерной консоли?

Comment: В показанном вами HTML-коде нет форм с id addToCartForm или removeFromCartForm